# How urination prior to blood test may give error?

Tags: physiology, lab-techniques, blood-circulation, excreta

[image]

Source: [Textbook of  Practical Physiology, 4th Edition](http://www.orientblackswan.com/BookDescription?isbn=978-81-7371-996-7&id=23&t=c)

> according to it urination within 30 minutes is a precollection factor that may alter the results of blood test.

I am unable to comprehend how urination could affect the blood sample. Urination will just result in excretion of urine already formed and stored in the urinary bladder, so how its loss could lead to error in blood sample?

Comment: This is new  to me and rather baffling. I can't imagine how emptying your bladder affects a blood test. The entire first section of the text is about hematology and covers the subjects in a CBC, nothing else.

Comment: Please don't post text as a picture. It's harder to read and cannot be searched.

Comment: What is being sampled from the blood?

Comment: It's just a general guideline. However we mostly do CBC.